# Maintain Gamekit Bluetooth connection through whole app

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit

So I'm building a data collection app for my work, and we'd like to have two ipads running the app simultaneously while both maintaining the same info.  So I ran some tests with gamekit and I think it will work great, but I could only get it working on one view controller.  My problem is users will surf between three different view controllers while using the app and I don't know how to maintain that session and send data and listen for data regardless of which page you're on.  Is this something that the appdelegate could maintain?  Or perhaps a singleton class?  Could someone point me in the right direction?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Singleton class to send / receive commands from game kit. Also that singleton might send `NSNotifications`, so you can assign any of your view controllers to receive them (make them observers). I have implemented this in several games and it works fine.

Example:

```
#define kWGConnectionManagerDidOpenConnection   @"kWGConnectionManagerDidOpenConnection"
#define kWGConnectionManagerDidCloseConnection @"kWGConnectionManagerDidCloseConnection"

typedef enum {
    WGConnectionTypeUndefined,
    WGConnectionTypeServer,
    WGConnectionTypeClient
} WGConnectionType;

@interface WGAPIManager : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) WGConnectionType connectionType;

+ (WGAPIManager*) sharedInstance;

- (void) sendCommand:(NSString*) command;
```

So any class can use this singleton to send commands using game kit, and any class can be an observer of notifications

Comment: Excellent, that's pretty much what I was hoping for.  Thank you!